# ListBox Item with different ForeColors

Tags: vb.net

How to put different `ForeColor` for each item in a `ListBox`? [image]

Picture above is an example of a control in DevExpress.

Comment: VBA or VB.NET? Clear that out and leave proper tag

Comment: I have edited my `tags`, @DisplayName. Thank you.

Comment: If you're talking WinForms, you'd need to owner-draw the items. That's something you can search for.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I was able to change the color for each item. What I want is to have different forecolors (3 colors, just like image above) for each item in listBox.

Comment: Are you saying that you implemented owner-drawing?  If so then what you draw in each item is completely up to you.  If you want to draw text in multiple colours then you need to call `DrawString` multiple times and provide the appropriate `Color` each time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for the idea. I was able to create what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to push it through. Thanks, jmcilhinney.
[image]

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(e As DrawItemEventArgs)
    e.DrawBackground()
    If e.State = DrawItemState.Focus Then e.DrawFocusRectangle()
    If e.Index < 0 OrElse e.Index >= Items.Count Then Return
    Dim item As String = Items(e.Index)
    Dim lists As String() = item.Split(",")
    Dim brush As Brush() = {Brushes.Blue, Brushes.DarkOrange, Brushes.Black, Brushes.Red}
    Dim current As String = String.Empty
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
    If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
        current = String.Join(" ", lists)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(current, e.Font, Brushes.White, e.Bounds)
    Else
        For i As Integer = 0 To lists.Count - 1
            Dim size As SizeF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(current, e.Font)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lists(i), e.Font, brush(i), size.Width, e.Bounds.Top, StringFormat.GenericDefault)
            current &= lists(i) & " "
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: One point to note is that you don't need to create and destroy a `SolidBrush` for a standard `Color`.  For instance, you can use `Brushes.White` in your `If` block.  For your `Else` block, store `Brushes.Blue`, etc, in an array instead of `Color` values.

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks again! xD